# I want to setup my own Tor implemintation, what should I take for?

Tags: security

I have download latest [source](https://git.torproject.org/tor.git).

Am I must to change default hard-coded 9 nodes and default ports 9001,9030 only?

How much nodes should I setup around the world for small group of confederates?

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking at all. What do you mean by "my own Tor implementation"? How should it be different from the standard Tor? Please explain in more details what do you want to achieve.

Comment: do you just want your own custom Tor network?

Comment: Exactly, I just want to setup my private Tor network.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the DirServer configuration option to point at your own directory authorities. The man page describes what the arguments are.

A good way to learn about how to run your own network is to use [Chutney](https://gitweb.torproject.org/chutney.git) to set up a small network on your local machine and look at how the configuration is done there. Beware that Chutney sets configuration option TestingTorNetwork which makes the network less secure. You might not want that on your own network with real traffic.

The anonymity of a Tor network is partly a function of the number of relays -- more relays give better anonymity. The number and type of users are other factors.