# Best way to set up a Tor lab?

Tags: relays, configuration, directory, research

What would be the best [and cheapest] way to set up a private Tor network for testing and experimentation?

A rough size estimate is that it should consist of 12 or more onion-routers and should be usable for experimenting with both standard Tor and Tor hidden services.

Comment: Looks like duplicate. See my question: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/498/i-want-to-setup-my-own-tor-implemintation-what-should-i-take-for

Comment: @polarbearonthewhitesnow: As far as I see it your question deals with another aspect. So I don't consider this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way is to emulate the network, such as with [ExperimenTor](https://crysp.uwaterloo.ca/software/exptor/) (which uses virtual machines) or [Shadow](http://shadow.github.io/) (which uses a discrete event simulator).

With Shadow (which I have more experience with), a 20 node network should [fit in 4 GB of RAM](https://github.com/shadow/shadow/wiki/Using-the-scallion-plug-in#scalability) such as on a Amazon EC2 m1.large server.

Another option is [Chutney](https://gitweb.torproject.org/chutney.git), which is simpler than either ExperimenTor or Shadow, but is still in need of some development work.

Answer (score 3):

If you did for some reason need discrete machines, some single-board computers would be good inexpensive candidates; Raspberry Pi is a bit slow, and 1024MB of RAM is better than 512MB if you're going to build a lot of circuits.

Candidates:

- Raspberry Pi (1 ARMv6 core, safely overclockable to at least 950MHz, 512MB RAM)
- BeagleBone Black (1 ARMv7 core [IIRC], runs real Debian armhf, 512MB RAM)
- Cubieboard 2 (dual ARMv7 cores, 1GHz, 1024MB RAM, runs Cubian, which is Debian armhf plus hardware specific stuff)

Comment: @Steven can you please explain how to set up hidden service in Shadow?